# How to create a checkbox menu with name of files in alphabetical order?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this peace of code which I use to create a checkbox menu in which I can select itens based on the names of the documents in a folder.
But this menu is always created with the last modified files first, and not alphabetical order, even if the files in my Google account Drive are arranged for display the files in alphabetical order. Is there a way to get these files to be shown in alphabetical order?

```
function showList(folderID) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {
    file = files[file];
    var thesesName = file.getName();
    var thesesId = file.getId();
    var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
    for (var child = 0; child < thesesDoc.getNumChildren(); child++){
    var thesesFirstParagraph = thesesDoc.getChild(child);
    var thesesType = thesesFirstParagraph.getText();
      if (thesesType != ''){
        var newArray = [thesesName, thesesType, thesesId];
        arrayList.push(newArray);
        break;
         }
      }
   }
   (...)
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length)); 
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
      panel.add(checkbox);
   }
   var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
   panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 400);
   scroll.add(panel);
   app.add(scroll);
   mydoc.show(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, the sorting order in your screen has nothing to do with the order returned by the API, these are separate things.

You can sort the files alphabetically easily on your `arrayList` after you've finished filling it. e.g.

```js
  for (var file in files) {
    //...

        break;
      }
    }
  }

  arrayList.sort(); //after you finish, before you create the checkbox list

  panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length)); 
  //...
```

Comment: Thanks, @HenriqueAbreu! Since I was looking for a sorting with case unsensitive, I used this piece of code: `arrayList.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
  });`